# Replication from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

We are moving our production databases from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012.

We need to prepare our fall-back plan, if something goes wrong then we will stop using 2012 servers. For this we need to plan moving our production data from 2012 servers to old 2005 servers.

Suggested options are

1. Use linked servers
2. Use a third party tool such as Red Gate SQL Data Compare.

Can someone suggest any recommended approach to do this?

Thanks,
SanjayH

Answer (score 0):

2 .Use a third party tool such as Red Gate SQL Data Compare.
You can use this option when the database is small, but it's not good when then database is big.
I suggest use the function copy database on SQL Server Management Studio. Other way you can set Compatibility level (database Properties>Option): 2005 Backup and restore it on SQL 2005

Comment: You can't restore a database from a higher version of the engine to a lower one. The on disk structures change between major versions (i.e. SQL 2005 → SQL 2008) and the lower version of the engine flat out will not understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It's funny that you mentioned replication in the title but didn't consider transactional replication as a solution to your problem. Depending on whether you're using any of the data types introduced after SQL 2005 (i.e. geo-spatial, hierarchyid), this could work for you.